# Pronunciacion de las frases como "he + e-verbo" y "ha + a-verbo"

Tags: gramática, pronunciación, conversación

En las frases como "lo h**a a**cabado", "lo h**e he**cho", muchas veces las escucho pronunciadas como si fuesen "lo acabado", "lo hecho" -- sin "ha" y "he" **completamente.** Y no como "lo a-acabado", "lo e-hecho", con "a" y "e" dobles o largas.

¿Es así en las conversaciones? ¿En todos o solo algunos, algún tipo de gente suele pronunciarlas así?

Y, gramaticalmente, ¿es incorrecto?

Comment: Yo vivo en una zona donde solemos hablar rápido y comiéndonos parte de las palabras, y aun así cuando pronunciamos "he hecho" o "ha acabado" a pesar de que efectivamente las palabras se unen se nota un alargamiento de la vocal inicial del verbo: "heecho" o "aacabado". Puede que sea poco apreciable pero está ahí.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con el comentario previo y la respuestade pablodf76; no logro imaginarme, ni aún haciéndolo intencionalmente, el omitir completamente el sonido de "ha" o "he" en estos ejemplos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice la prueba de grabarme diciendo cosas como “lo he hecho siempre así”, “lo hecho, hecho está” y otras, para observar después el espectrograma de lo grabado. Hay variación según dónde está ubicada la expresión, pero la entonación es diferente.

Cuando digo “lo hecho” al comienzo de la enunciación, separo con claridad las vocales: *o-é*. Cuando digo “lo he hecho”, las dos primeras palabras (el pronombre y el auxiliar) se unen en una sola palabra fonéticamente hablando, y la segunda (el participio) queda aparte: *oe-é*. La separación en sí puede ser muy pequeña (no es una pausa). El efecto lo da la entonación. A veces es muy sutil y no se nota la diferencia.